# Angular - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise) in Angular 7

Tags: angular, laravel

I have a strange error. When I clicked on each of the menu to open a page, I got this error:

[image: uncaught error]

route.php

```
    public function login(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password'=> 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
    }

    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

    if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 400);
    }

    $current_user = $request->email;

    return response()->json([
    'access_token' => $token,
    'token_type' => 'bearer',
    'current_user' => $current_user,
    'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
    ], 200);
} 

public function indexBilling()
{           
        $billings = Billing::all();  
    return $billings;                   
}  
public function indexShortcode(Request $request)
{
     if(Auth::user()->id == 1)
         $shortcodes = Shortcode::all();
     else 
         $shortcodes = Shortcode::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
     return $shortcodes;      
}
```

api.php

```
Route::post('login', 'ApiController@login');
Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');
Route::post('logout', 'ApiController@logout');
Route::post('sendPasswordResetLink', 'ResetPasswordController@sendEmail');
Route::post('resetPassword', 'ChangePasswordController@process');
Route::middleware('jwt.auth')->get('me', function(Request $request) {
return auth()->user();
});

Route::post('storeShortcode', 'ApiController@storeShortcode');
Route::get('indexShortcode', 'ApiController@indexShortcode');
Route::get('showShortcode/{id}', 'ApiController@showShortcode');
Route::get('editShortcode/{id}', 'ApiController@editShortcode');
Route::post('updateShortcode/{id}', 'ApiController@updateShortcode');
Route::get('deleteShortcode/{id}', 'ApiController@deleteShortcode');
```

angular

auth.server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(
private router: Router,
private auth: AuthService) {}
```

canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable | Promise | 
    boolean {

```
  if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    // logged in so return true
    return true;
  }

  // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
  this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url 
}});

  return true;
  }
}
```

I am unable to open any item. It loads nothing and I got this error on the console.

app.module.ts

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination'; // <-- import the module
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter'; //importing the module
import { OrderModule } from 'ngx-order-pipe';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { SlimLoadingBarModule } from 'ng2-slim-loading-bar';

import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';
import { JarwisService } from './services/jarwis.service';
import { TokenService } from './services/token.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AfterLoginService } from './services/after-login.service';
import { BeforeLoginService } from './services/before-login.service';
import { SnotifyModule, SnotifyService, ToastDefaults } from 'ng-snotify';
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SmsShortcodeUpdateComponent } from './components/sms/sms-shortcode-update/sms-shortcode-update.component';

import { DirectivesModule } from 'src/app/directives/directives.module';
import { LogoutComponent } from './components/logout/logout.component';
import { TopupWalletCreateComponent } from './components/payments/topup-wallet-create/topup-wallet-create.component';
import { TopupWalletDetailComponent } from './components/payments/topup-wallet-detail/topup-wallet-detail.component';
import { TopupWalletEditComponent } from './components/payments/topup-wallet-edit/topup-wallet-edit.component';
import { PremiumSmsProductDetailComponent } from './components/sms/premium-sms-product-detail/premium-sms-product-detail.component';
import { SmsShortcodeDetailComponent } from './components/sms/sms-shortcode-detail/sms-shortcode-detail.component';
 //import { LoadscriptDirective } from './directives/loadscript.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LandingComponent,
    NotfoundComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SmsComponent,
    SmsShortcodeUpdateComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SlimLoadingBarModule,//including into imports
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
    NgxPaginationModule,//Pagination
    Ng2SearchPipeModule, //including into imports
    OrderModule,  //// importing the sorting package here    
    OrderModule,  //// importing the sorting package here
    SnotifyModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, UserService,AuthenticationService,JarwisService,TokenService,AuthService,AfterLoginService,BeforeLoginService,
    { provide: 'SnotifyToastConfig', useValue: ToastDefaults},
    SnotifyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Are you importing HttpErrorHandler in the code? can you show us along with your app.module.ts?

Comment: I have just added app.module.ts

Comment: It seems like you are using HttpErrorHandler, but not provided in module, using `providedIn` syntax.  Or you are using the service, before its instance can be created. If that is the case, you might need to use `forwardRef()`.

Comment: Clicking on network tab and then response can reveal server errors.

Comment: Also you might wanna check your api auth driver, since JWT authentication uses `JWTAuth::attempt($credentials))`